# How to deposit $9,900 in $100 bills when I only have accounts like Schwab and CapitalOne

Tags: united-states, banking, cash, deposits, cashier-check

I sold a car and have a bunch of cash that I'd like to put into my CapitalOne savings account.

I live in the Atlanta suburbs, where CapitalOne has no branches and no ATMs that accept deposits. Their rep told me to visit CVS pharmacy 10 times over the next 2 months and deposit the cash there (to be under their daily deposit limit).

To skip that hassle, I'd rather pay ~$10 for a cashier's check of $9,900 that I could then use the CapitalOne app to deposit.

I also have a Schwab bank account and American Express bank account, but those don't allow depositing cash either.

I visited a Chase bank today, but they wouldn't sell me a cashier's check unless I opened an account with them.

I've been unable to find a bank that allows it.

What do you recommend?

Comment: I guess I could do 10 money orders at https://moneyservices.kroger.com/money-orders/ for $1 each, but that still feels silly.

Comment: This is why I bank local (while also banking remotely).

Comment: Warning. Depositing smaller sums of money multiple times to get under limits is known as "structuring" and *might* be illegal.

Comment: @DM I appreciate your heads-up! Personally I feel it would be ludicrous for the government to claim that me trying to put money into my savings account is a crime. The small amounts aren't my choice. I very much look forward to when blockchain makes all of this nonsense irrelevant.

Comment: @Ryan the law prohibits "structuring", i.e.: breaking sums down into smaller amounts to avoid FinCEN reports. FinCEN reports are statutorily mandated for cash transactions of $10K or more, which you're very close to. So breaking your deposit into smaller chunks may be *perceived* as structuring even if that's not what you intended.

Comment: You hope the bills are genuine...

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Even though the bank wouldn't sell me a cashier's check, at least they were willing to scan the bills and confirm that they weren't counterfeit.

Answer (score 5):

It would have been better to ask for a cashier's check from your buyer instead of cash, but I guess that ship has sailed.

You can buy money orders from a local post office, or as you mentioned in your comment - some local stores. You'd need to do 10 of them, since they have $1000 limit.

Alternatively you can consider opening an account with some local bank, depositing there and then transferring. I doubt any bank would convert your cash into their cashier's check without you having an account there ("know your customer" laws and such).

Comment: +1 for opening a convenience account. I set one up just so I could drop spare change into it....

Comment: Always check the fees so they don't drain all your money.